# Problems with os.stat(), os.major() and os.minor() on Linux

Tags: python

I am running Python 3.6.7 on by Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. 
Below is a code snap of the interactive shell:

```
>>>info = os.stat('/dev/tty').st_dev
>>>info
6
>>>os.major(info)
0
>>>os.minor(info)
6
```

It says the major:minor is 0:6. However, the bash command ***stat*** shows otherwise that the major:minor number should be 5:0 instead.
Incidentally, the output of the info is 6. So, could it be the problem of os.stat()?

Comment: `/dev/tty` is a character special device, use `st_rdev`.

Comment: AChampion is right. Thanks for the timely reply.